# wp_get_attachment_image_src() not working even when correct id is passed

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$images =& get_posts( array (
                'post_status' => 'private',
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_excerpt' => $revision_message,
                'post_type' => 'document',
));
if ( empty($images) ) {
    // no attachments here
} else {
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) { 
    if($attachment->post_author==$author){
    $ids= $attachment->ID;
    $a=wp_get_attachment_image_src($ids,'thumbnail');
    echo $a."--";
    }}
}
```

$ids is printing correct post id but when it passes to wp_get_attachment_image_src nothing is returned.
please help guys. i am a newbie to wordpress development and my job is on the line. please help.

Comment: You've said "$ids is printing correct post id" - do you meant the correct attachment ID?  `wp_get_attachment_image_src` expects an attachment ID, which is different to the post ID

Comment: I didnt knew attachment ID is different to the post ID. thanx @mike.

Comment: I'll pop it in an answer so you can mark as correct for others.  Glad it's sorted

Comment: In addition to Mikes comment, check this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said "$ids is printing correct post id" - do you meant the correct attachment ID? `wp_get_attachment_image_src` expects an attachment ID, which is different to the post ID